# k-center in a large graph (road-network)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, approximation

I'm currently looking for a way to solve the *k*-center problem on a large, sparse graph. The data comes from openstreetmap and I want to place *k* pizza-delivery-branches in the city in such way as the distance to any node in the graph from a branch is minimized.

---

**Example:** Where should I place 3 pizza-delivery-branches to cover the city the best?

[image: Example]

---

**Problem:** The graph contains approximately 50,000 to 250,000 nodes (data from openstreetmap).

**Simplifaction:** The solution doesn't have to be perfect. An approximation will suffice. *k* will be smaller than 20. Runtimes of several hours are ok.

I can't wait to hear from your ideas how to solve the problem on such a large real-world-graph (road-network).

Comment: _k_ will be smaller than 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following greedy algorithm is a 2-approximation for instances where the travel time of each road is the same in both directions. (Ignoring one-way streets shouldn't distort travel times too much.)

Choose the first center arbitrarily. For each subsequent center, choose the vertex farthest from the existing centers. Using the multiple-source extension of Dijkstra's algorithm (initialize the priority queue to contain all of the existing centers with distance 0), a good implementation running on contemporary hardware with parameters n=250,000 and k=20 I reckon should take at most a second or two.

Comment: I think I'll try that. But I'm concerned about the ignorance of one-way streets because motorways are very fast and very long one-way streets and will distort travel times very much.

Comment: @user2033412 There's no good worst-case algorithm that handles one-way streets. Real-world road networks are of course not so adversarial, and assuming no one-way streets is the simplest **theoretical** assumption to get around the theoretical problems. You don't have to make your implementation ignore one-way streets.

Comment: So I will implement it to be aware of one-way streets and have a look on how it performs. I think intuitively the results for _k_ near to 20 will be good but the results for _k_ near to 1 will get poorer.

Comment: I expect the following performance: My implementation of _Dijkstra's algorithm_ takes about 30ms for 100,000 nodes. As this algorithms simply takes 20 runs of Dijkstra it will expect this algorithm to take less than a second to finish.

Comment: @user2033412 Ah, it seems I have forgotten the right number for Dijkstra. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I guess there are tons of heuristics and tuning parameters in choosing the first node and the next node. For example: The first node should be located somewhere in the geographic ‘middle’ of the graph. And all other nodes should not be located on the ‘border’ of the graph. Is there any research being done in there heuristics?

Comment: @user2033412 That's an excellent question, to which I don't know the answer despite recently having co-authored a manuscript on approximating k-center in planar graphs (that algorithm is unlikely to be practical as-is). I will mention that you can use this approximation to find many more centers than necessary (but many fewer than the number of vertices in the graph), then form a complete graph on those centers with distances and use another to find the actual k centers, without losing too much in the way of quality.

Comment: What algorithm could choose the actual _k_ centers from the potential – let's say – 1000 centers found by the greedy approach?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35695/discussion-between-user2033412-and-david-eisenstat)